# How do we handle changing the close reason on a question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

How should we handle if a question has been edited and the current reason for its closure no longer holds, but it is now close-worthy for another reason? For example if it was closed as a duplicate, then edited to be different from that question, but it is now unclear or POB.

It could technically be achieved by reopening and then closing it again, but voting to reopen a question that should be closed seems counter-intuitive.

Another option would be to leave it closed and add a comment with your opinion. But the close reason bar is so much more prominent than a comment that it might become lost. I feel *some* notification should be given to the querent.

Is there a community consensus? If not, what is your take on this?

Comment: FYI, usually if we're in the middle of working on a question and the author is still actively interacting with us, we shouldn't fret about the close reason -- the fact it's closed is enough, and we can signal to the author what's going on through dialog with them that they're still reading. “OK, it's no longer unclear, but your edit also means this is too broad. Could you scope this down by (...)” and similar are fairly common ways of responding to revisions that change the nature of the problem, and usually generate response. (Sometimes mainly exasperation, so we should be compassionate.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would flag for a moderator to act, as they can open the question and close it with the new reason by themselves.